# Center page in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I am trying to center page on IE. If I force quirk-mode by adding `<!-- some comment -->` before DOCTYPE declaration `margin: auto;` doesn't work properly and page is adjusted to the left. If I remove the comment page is centered, but some other elements are in mess. Could you give me some hints how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have any floats on your container? It might be prudent to post up your bare-bones HTML and CSS...

Comment: Do you have a width specified for your container? I might be wrong, but I don't think auto margin will work unless there's some sort of width on it. Like BenM said, if you post your code, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: solution: remove quirksmode, and then fix the other things which are in a mess. If you're relying on quirksmode to solve your problems, then you're storing up bigger problems for yourself in the future. Bite the bullet now and tidy up your broken layout.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` for the body using CSS usually does the trick.

Forcing quirks mode probably isn't a great idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, being in quirks mode is not where you want to be so quit doing that. The problem will lie with the rest of the markup but, unless you give us a link or a jsfiddle with the complete markup, anything we say will just be a wild guess.

Does the page work in a modern browser (anything but IE)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 50% margin, and a negative left position with half of your element size:

```
position: relative;
width: 600px;
margin-left: 50%;
left: -300px;
```